# Trying to attach resistor to MacBook logic board (a1278, 820-3115-b)

Tags: resistors, soldering, surface-mount

On my logic board, I knocked off a loose resistor when I was replacing my battery. The resistor was r6700, which is located right at the edge of the board and its function is to detect headphones. So now when I plug in my headphones, it thinks I plugged in an optical cable.

I got a donor board, but unfortunately r6700 was removed along with the headphone jack. So I found a resistor r7832 which has the same rating as r6700 and I'm trying to reattach it to the board, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting the solder to stick onto the board.

I removed r7832 by dropping liquid flux (Kester) on the donor board and using a bit of tin solder with a drag tip. I managed to lift it off the board. I checked the schematics and matched the ground. I tried to attach the resistor to my actual board by first adding flux and solder and running through the pads, then placing the resistor on the pads and using a heat gun to ease it into position. Afterwards I try to add some solder to keep it in place, but whenever I try to solder the thing, it moves. I tried placing pressure on top, but I can't seem to get a good stable grip on it.

Any tips on how to keep it in place when soldering? Am I attaching it wrong? Or any other problems I should be aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soldering surface-mount components is tricky, and requires the proper tools and experience. Indiscriminate use of a heat-gun is more likely **to destroy the mother-board** than to fix the issue. Lumps of solder or burned traces may also make repair difficult or impossible.

The best solution would be to find an experienced technician with the proper equipment, such as an advanced student in EE or a computer-repair specialist to reinstall it.

If you insist on installing it yourself and *can't* find the equipment to use, you could try an [electrically-conductive cement](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H861L7J)... but that might not last, particularly if you remove the board again.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to use the conductive cement. Also, both resistors (r6700 and r7832) are both 10k 5% 1/16 W MF-LF 0402, how would I know if the resistors are correct value?

Comment: Sorry, the replacement should be fine. I'd assumed the r6700 was 6700 ohm.